# Add competitors section to company page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

The company page has some nice information such as founded, whether a company is private / public, as well as number of employees.  Could we also add a section for competitors.  For instance, If I am interested in working on embedded devices and I'm on bose's company page, it could also link me to other company pages that are competitors - for instance - harmon kardon.

Comment: I seriously doubt companies would be open to that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be like us inserting links to other people's user pages in your About Me. That's your space, we shouldn't meddle with it.

Also, companies pay us to promote their pages in ads on Stack Overflow. If we put a competitors section that means they're paying us money to promote other companies. Doesn't seem like the right behavior.

Comment: You're right I forgot companies are paying for this stuff.